# Django .first() method cuts first digit from a Decimal

Tags: python, django

I am seeing really strange behavior when using `.first()` method on a `QuerySet`. After calling the method, first digit from a Decimal value gets cut.

Models:

```
class Distributions(models.Model):
    distribution_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    months_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    activity_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    value_in_percentage = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=8, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True
    )
    value_in_units = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=16, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True
    )
    distribution_type = models.ForeignKey(
        DistributionType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True
    )
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Monthly values:

```
data = Distributions.objects.all()
monthly_values = data.values("distribution_type_id", "activity_date").annotate(tsum=Sum("value_in_units"))
```

Code:

```
def _get_month_value(self, id: int, month_values: QuerySet) -> int:
        print("----------")
        print(month_values)
        print(month_values.filter(id=id).values('tsum'))
        print(month_values.filter(id=id).values('tsum').first())
        print(month_values.filter(id=id).values('tsum')[0])
```

The outputs are as follows:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'tsum': Decimal('519')}, {'id': 3, 'tsum': Decimal('1019')}, 
{'id': 5, 'tsum': Decimal('0')}, {'id': 9, 'tsum': Decimal('0')}]>
<QuerySet [{'tsum': Decimal('519')}]>
{'tsum': Decimal('19')}
{'tsum': Decimal('519')}
```

As you can see for `id` 1 the original value is 519 but after I call the `first()` method it gets turned into a 19. This does not happend if I manually call the first item in QueySet using `[0]`.

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you also update your question with the model structure

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM added, sorry :)

Comment: do this and share records `data = Distributions.objects.filter(id=id).values("value_in_units")` without annotate

Comment: @HemalPatel but without annotate I wont be able to get grouped by sum of `value_in_units`

Comment: yes i just wanted to see other records. ofc you wont get total without annotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the function `first` use FIRST, TOP, or LIMIT in SQL query and SUM in the select.

Django executes the query only when you need the value, so the `first()` executes all the query and filters elements that the sum uses.

You can see de sql query with `print(queryset.query)`.

In your code, the sql is `SELECT CAST(SUM("app_distributions"."value_in_units") AS NUMERIC) AS "tsum" FROM "app_distributions" WHERE "app_distributions"."id" = N GROUP BY "app_distributions"."distribution_type_id" "app_distributions"."activity_date"` (or similar), and when you use `first()`, django add more sql and only get the first record and sum only this record.

Comment: My solution:

1- If you need to get the first only in a part of the code, use index (`[0]`) but you need to check the existence before (`queryset.exists()`).
2- If you need to use the queryset in different parts of code and it uses the functions first or last, you can create a custom manager that checks the existence and get by index (`0` or `-1`).